# Finding the Second Highest Value for Multiple Groupings in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on an election database within mysql and was looking for some help regarding a query. As is, I can currently find the winners of all elections using the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Office, c.Election, c.fName, c.mName, c.lName, MAX(v.votes) as Votes
-> FROM candidates as c, (SELECT DISTINCT c_id, COUNT(c_id) as votes FROM votes
-> GROUP BY c_id) as v
-> WHERE c.c_id = v.c_id
-> GROUP BY Office, Election;
```

Now I am looking to find the runner up for each election. I have attempted the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Office, c.Election, c.fName, c.mName, c.lName, MAX(v.votes) as Votes
-> FROM candidates as c, (SELECT DISTINCT c_id, COUNT(c_id) as votes FROM votes
-> GROUP BY c_id) as v, (SELECT DISTINCT c_id, COUNT(c_id) as votes FROM votes
-> GROUP BY c_id) as v2
-> WHERE c.c_id = v.c_id
-> AND v.votes < v2.votes
-> GROUP BY Office, Election;
```

Which successfully returns the runner up for the first election, however returns the winner for all following election. How can I improve my query such that it applies the runner up condition to all elections in the set?

EDIT: This is for mysql 5.1

Comment: Also use proper `GROUP BY`.  That statement should not be able to run.

Comment: MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: This can be done very easily with [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) introduced in MySQL 8.

Comment: This is for mysql 5.1 specifically

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a join condition between Votes tables. Try below -

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Office
               ,c.Election
               ,c.fName
               ,c.mName
               ,c.lName
               ,MAX(v.votes) as Votes
FROM candidates as c
JOIN (SELECT c_id
            ,COUNT(c_id) as votes
      FROM votes
      GROUP BY c_id) as v ON c.c_id = v.c_id
JOIN (SELECT c_id
            ,COUNT(c_id) as votes
      FROM votes
      GROUP BY c_id) as v2 ON v.c_id = v2.c_id
                          AND v.votes < v2.votes
GROUP BY c.Office
        ,c.Election
        ,c.fName
        ,c.mName
        ,c.lName
```

Also, I have converted your old join syntax to new ANSI style join which is more simpler to read.